# IntelliJ Idea with Git: when automatic merge crashed, how can I continue to merge manually

Tags: java, git, ide, merge, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ Idea with Git.
When I pull from repository, I get following error:

"
...CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in server..."

Then pull fails.

Questions are:

1. Does IntelliJ Idea displays any log of what happend exactly? How do I see it?
2. How can I continue merge manually from the same point (where it failed)?

Comment: 1. shelve everything. 2. create new branch from current and again resolve conflict ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like you've got a conflict during merge. Go to the `Changes` View and see if there are any unmerged files. Then invoke `Resolve Conflicts`, choose what to take from your changes and theirs, and commit.

You may also want to try `Update Project` for more intelligent pulling from the tracked branch.

Comment: where can I find 'Update Project' option?

Comment: `VCS` | `Update Project` menu.

Comment: The Resolve Conflict merging window has a button to auto-apply all non-conflicting changes. I never notice that before.

Answer (score 2):

1. Double shift, than search "*resolve conflicts*"
2. Resolve the conflicts.
3. Commit your changes.

Done.